# Cannot access scope members in template-less component

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, angular-controller

Trying to use a component without specifying a template.

Problem: the HTML doesn't seem to have access to any isolated scope members, namely: `hideMe` & `testMessage`

```
<html>

  <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      angular.module('test', [])

          .component('testComponent', {

            bindings: {
            },

            controller: function() {

              var ctrl = this;

              ctrl.$onInit = function() {

                ctrl.hideMe = true;
                ctrl.testMessage = 'hello';

              }

            }

        });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="test">

    <test-component ng-hide="$ctrl.hideMe">

      <p>Controller message: {{ $ctrl.testMessage }}</p>

    </test-component>

  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wu6a3SiNOXJSfFp1NhzX?p=preview)

Am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you're looking for ngTransclude ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: @svarog I was hoping to avoid transclusion to avoid an additional HTML tag being inserted

Comment: You either have to use ngTransclude or move the inner html to a template

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, I was hoping that limitation could be avoided. Guess that also means that ng-hide (declared on the component's uppermost element) cannot read a variable from the new isolated scope too? This seems problematic because then you have a visible element that you'd like hidden in the markup.

Comment: Correct about `ng-hide` on the outer tag . It's scope is the parent scope, not the component isolated scope which is only in effect **inside** the component

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for clearing that up - it seems my way of thinking about the defining component element was wrong. So lets say I use transclusion which then nests the `<test-component>` HTML into say a parent `<div>`. Is it possible to use `ng-hide` on the newly created uppermost `<div>` using a variable from the new isolated scope?

Comment: Only by using bindings to parent scope. Why can't you use `ng-hide` inside the component instead?

Comment: @charlietfl It creates a UI problem if the uppermost element cannot be hidden. The component I'm building is actually a loading spinner that sits in the `<body>` root and when visible overlays the entire page. So not being able to hide it would mean the content below would be inaccessible. Maybe a nested isolated scope is the answer...

Comment: Lots of ways to approach this, really not that difficult. Not sure what exact issue is with spinner. Can use angular events to tell component to hide/show, or use a service that can be shared across whole app

Comment: @charlietfl Well, I was trying to stick to the 'angular way'. So rather than using jqLite to manually hide the parent from within the component controller, I instead wanted to use `ng-hide` on the parent based on a value within the newly created isolated scope. The main issue is that the newly created uppermost element, which will probably be the `<div>` in `<div><test-component></test-component></div>`, has to fill the entire screen (css: `position: absolute; width: 100%; height 100%`), so it must be able to be hidden when the spinner is inactive.

Comment: That's no problem when you move that `<div>` inside the template and position it absolute. Then use events or a service to communicate across other parts of the app

Comment: Primitive example using angular events https://plnkr.co/edit/Xu1cdde0V2wG52ob5DoN?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for that, very useful. Following suit, I'm now adding the HTML to the component template value, which greatly simplifies the issues.